# Retrieving value from DataTextField of kendo MVC combo and assigning it to the viewmodel

Tags: kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-combobox

I am implementing MVC kendo Combo box control in my MVC application. The kendo combo box control contains a model property bound to the value and text property respectively. The text property contains a concatenated model property called CompanyCodeCompany.  I basically need to extract the company code and assign it to the company code property in the viewmodel as I need that value while saving to the database. Please note that I need both the country code and company code. Currently the combo box value field is bound to CountryCode. Currently the combobox is populated using SalesOrganisation viewmodel and the main form posts the data using newrequest viewmodel.  I tried CompanyCodeCompany property on the new request viewmodel. But that doest seem to work either.I understand that this piece of code in combo  @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode) will bind only the countrycode. The ideal way would have been to retrieve the company code value from salesorganisation and assign it to new request viewmodel directly in razor.

I am not sure on the approach to take to retrieve the companycode value.

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Company, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="editor-field">

                       @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)
                        // .Name("SalesOrganisation")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
                        .DataTextField("CompanyCodeCompany")
                        .DataValueField("CountryCode")
                        .Filter("contains")
                        .MinLength(3)
                        .Value(@user.DefaultCountryCode)
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                        .ServerFiltering(true)
                        )
                     )
                    </div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Company, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Sales Organisation Viewmodel**

```
 public class SalesOrganisationViewModel
    {
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }

        public string CompanyCode { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sales Organisation")]
        public string Company { get; set; }


        public string CompanyCodeCompany
        {
            get
            {
                return CompanyCode + " - " + Company;
            }
        }

    }
```

**NewRequest ViewModel**

```
public class NewRequestViewModel
    {

        private string name;

        [Display(Name = "Request Id")]
        public int RequestID { get; set; }
        public int CustomerMasterDataId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Customer Number")]
        public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Customer Name")]
        public string Name1 { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Customer Group")]
        public string CustomerGroup { get; set; }

        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
       public string CompanyCodeCompany { get; set; }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your other question: Basically, handle the change event on the combo box and set the value of the Company Code. So first, add a HiddenFor to your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyCode)
```

Now handle the change event:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
    .DataTextField("CompanyCodeCompany")
    .DataValueField("CountryCode")
    .Filter("contains")
    .MinLength(3)
    .Value(@user.DefaultCountryCode)
    .Events(e => e.Change(onComboChange))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("RequestHeader_SalesOrganisation", "Request").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
    .ServerFiltering(true)
    )
```

Then access the dataitem and set the value:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onComboChange(e) {
            var dataItem = e.sender.dataItem();

            if (dataItem) {
                $("#CompanyCode").val(dataItem.CompanyCode);
            };
        };

    </script>
}
```

Now both country code and company code should post back. Here is that sample of how it the binding part works: http://jsfiddle.net/sg53719/74LwhebL/1/